# How can i add a keylistener to my Gui in java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a simple Gui

```
public Gui(){
    ablak = new JFrame("Snake game");
    ablak.setVisible(true);
    ablak.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    ablak.setFocusable(true);
    ablak.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ablak.add(new Grid());
    ablak.add(new Key());
}
```

And a key class to listner to keyevents

```
package snake;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Key implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


}
```

As you can see pressing the Up arrow key should say something like Hi, but nothing happens.
If i try to add(new Key()) in Gui class it gives an error.
What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `addKeyListener()` method:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame ablak = new JFrame("Snake game");
        ablak.setVisible(true);
        ablak.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        ablak.setFocusable(true);
        ablak.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ablak.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
             @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                        System.out.println("Hi");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }
        });
        ablak.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then add a JButton to the mess, and what's going to happen? It will fail, that's what.

Comment: Not to mention the exceptions that will be thrown if/when that code does work!

Comment: The code does work and it does throw exceptions due to them being thrown in the implemented methods.  I left these in since they were included in the OP's source.  Maybe he wants to implement those after he fixes this error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the tutorials first. You don't add KeyListeners with `add(...)` but rather with `addKeyListener(...)` since `add(...)` is for adding **component** only, but having said that, I wouldn't even use a KeyListener for this but rather Key Bindings which would help to fix the problems you will have in the future when focus prevents your KeyListener from working.

[Key Bindings tutorial Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

---

For example, compile and run Kevin Bowersox's program with my little Key Binding addtion:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame ablak = new JFrame("Snake game");
      ablak.setVisible(true);
      ablak.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
      ablak.setFocusable(true);
      ablak.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      ablak.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
               System.out.println("Hi from KeyListener");
            }
         }
      });
      ablak.setVisible(true);

      JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) ablak.getContentPane();
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = contentPane.getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = contentPane.getActionMap();

      String down = "down";
      inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), down);
      actionMap.put(down, new AbstractAction() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Hi from Key Binding");
         }
      });

   }
}
```

If you run it and press the up and down arrows, you'll see the responses from both a functioning KeyListener and Key Bindings.

But what if you add a JButton to the mix like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame ablak = new JFrame("Snake game");
      ablak.setVisible(true);
      ablak.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
      ablak.setFocusable(true);
      ablak.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      ablak.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
               System.out.println("Hi from KeyListener");
            }
         }
      });

      JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) ablak.getContentPane();
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = contentPane.getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = contentPane.getActionMap();

      String down = "down";
      inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), down);
      actionMap.put(down, new AbstractAction() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Hi from Key Binding");
         }
      });

      JButton fooButton = new JButton("Foo");
      contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      contentPane.add(fooButton);

      ablak.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

And then what happens after you press the button? Tell me which key handling routine works?