# Java key event not working

Tags: java

Hello i am trying to make the game pong. Now i am trying to move the paddle with my keyboard but it is not responding at all. Can anyone tell me what i am missing here? I can't figure it out what it is i am doing wrong.
The paddle is moving when i set the condition in the check to false so there is not a problem in moving it. Just getting the keyEvent to work.

What am i missing in the keyEvent?

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Paneel extends JPanel 
{
    private int height, width;
    private boolean moveLeft, moveRight, moveUp, moveDown, playerMoveLeft, 
    playerMoveRight, computerMoveLeft, computerMoveRight = false;
    private Timer timer;
    private Ball ball;
    private Paddle player, computer;

    public Paneel() 
    {
        ball = new Ball(994, 772);
        player = new Paddle(1, 994, 722);
        computer = new Paddle(2, 944, 722);
        TimerHandler timerHandler = new TimerHandler();
        timer = new Timer(20, timerHandler);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics pen)
    {
        super.paintComponent(pen);
        ball.drawBall(pen);
        player.drawPaddle(pen);
        computer.drawPaddle(pen);
        pen.drawString("" + getHeight() + " " + getWidth(), 50, 50);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) playerMoveLeft = true;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) playerMoveRight = 
        true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) playerMoveLeft = false;
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) playerMoveRight = 
        false;
    }

    public void movePlayer() 
    {
        if (playerMoveRight == true) player.moveDown();
        else if (playerMoveLeft == true) player.moveUp();
    }

    public void moveComputer() 
    {

    }

    public void resetBall()
    {

    }

    public void resetPlayer()
    {

    }

    public void resetComputer()
    {

    }

    class TimerHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use [addKeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener(java.awt.event.KeyListener)).. just having that method there does nothing by itself..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i add a keylistener to my Gui in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413910/how-can-i-add-a-keylistener-to-my-gui-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Its still not working

this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) playerMoveLeft = true;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) playerMoveRight = true;
   }
   
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
   {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) playerMoveLeft = false;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) playerMoveRight = false;
   }

   @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  });

Comment: A better solution would be to use the [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will reduce the likely hood that you post yet another question asking why you `KeyListener` won't respond to key events, even though you've registered